# Error near select using coalesce on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, coalesce

I have this query

```
select  bpl.id_employee as employeeId, 
    round(
        (
            sum(bppgt.nu_hours) + (sum(bppgt.nu_minutes::decimal)/60)
        ) - 
        coalesce(select sum(nu_horas), 0) 
            from boemulsa_sindical_hours 
            where fe_fecha_inicio >= '2019/12/01' 
            and fe_fecha_inicio <= '2019/12/31', 2) as hours,
    bri.nu_cod_incidence as incidenceCode, 
    min(bppgt.fe_date) as date
    from productions_people_general_tasks bppgt
    left join people bpl on bpl.id_employee = bppgt.id_employee
    left join general_tasks bgt on bgt.id_task = bppgt.id_task
    left join rrhh_incidences bri on bri.id_incidence = bgt.id_incidence
    where bppgt.fe_date >= '2019/12/01'         
    group by  bpl.id_employee
    order by bpl.id_employee
```

And I have this error, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «select»
LINE 6:    coalesce(select sum(nu_horas), 0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery requires its own set of parentheses.  However, an aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row.  So you can move the `coalesce()` inside the subuqery:

```
   (select coalesce(sum(nu_horas), 0) 
    from boemulsa_sindical_hours 
    where fe_fecha_inicio >= '2019/12/01'  and
          fe_fecha_inicio <= '2019/12/31'
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `coalesce` (and any other function), you can use a column/value directly:

```
select coalesce(1,2);
```

or if you want to use another query, it must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
select coalesce((select 1),2);
```

In you case, since you don't specify a `from`, it is likely that you want `coalesce(sum(nu_horas), 0)`

Comment: ok, i made this: " coalesce((select sum(nu_horas)), 0) " and i have the same error, but now near "from"

Comment: It seems you are missing a set of parenthese around the entire sub-query